# Changing only the home page layout in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, layout

If my whole site is using the default.ctp layout specified in apps/view/layouts/default.ctp, how do I change only the home page layout to use homepage.ctp and leave the rest of the site using default.ctp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Copy the `/cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php` into your `/app/controller/` dir and do either of the following:

- Add a line towards the end of `display()` to switch the layout if 'home' is requested:
  `if ($page == 'home') $this->layout = 'homepage';`
- Create a `home()` method (or named however you like) in which you set `$this->layout` and re-route the `/` route in `/app/config/routes.php` to use this new method.

**Edit:**
In summary, you need some custom method in which you'll set `$this->layout = 'homepage'`, that's all. You can do this in any of your controllers at any point, reusing the `PagesController` is just the most convenient and conventional way to do it in Cake.

Comment: Isn't overwriting the class a little smarter. I also guess that `$this->layout` can be called from some other function, something `init`-like.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the original `PagesController` - you can use routes to point to a custom controller and set `$this->layout` from there

Comment: @Franz What do you mean by "overwriting"?

Comment: @K Sure you can, but its a good idea to keep only the PagesController for static pages as per convention.

Comment: Cool, i just got this to work using the first point. Although I also noticed that the custom cms that another guy here at work wrote overrides this setting. So basically I just had to specify a template for the homepage through the cms. When I'm not using the cms though, I'll be sure to use this. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: For those new to cakephp please note that if using deceze's first solution the $this->layout = 'homepage'; line should go before the $this->render(join('/', $path)); line (the last line in the display function) as otherwise the layout won't be updated from the default one.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is now out of date, but gives the right approach.

In modern versions of CakePHP, the controller he asks you to make is already present and is:

```
/app/Controller/PagesController.php
```

I had a template called "loggedoff", and added this as follows, just before the `$this->render()` command (approx line 73).

```
$this->layout = 'loggedoff';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
class RegistrationsController extends AppController {
     public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Time');
     public $components = array('Session');

     public function login() {
         $this->layout = 'empty';
     } 
}
```

Just set the desired layout in the controller function.